# ArrayList<boolean[]> to Bitmap, best way?

Tags: android, bitmap

What is an efficient way (in terms of memory and cpu) to convert an `ArrayList<boolean[]>` or a `boolean[][]` into a `Bitmap`?

Does this way change if we know that the `Bitmap` must be modified or appended later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to convert your `boolean[][]` to an `int[]` and use [`setPixels`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). This is especially beneficial if you're going to do many pixel-level modifications later (just re-use the `int[]` and call `setPixels` again).

Comment: would this be preceded by a bitmap.create(width,height,config) ?

Comment: Yep. You have to create an empty bitmap of the correct size before using setPixels.